# Laravel - API return fields as string while they are int in the DB

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code:

```
$data['daily_missions'] = DailyMission::with(['userProgress' => function($q) use ($user){
            $q->where('user_id',$user->id);
            }])
        ->orderBy('diamonds')
        ->where('is_daily',1)
        ->get();
```

In the DB, most of the fields of the DailyMission / userProgress models are integers - but the API return them as string.

for example:

```
{
price: "123"
}
```

instead of:

```
{
price: 123
}
```

Any idea what can cause this issue?

Version:

```
"laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
```

Comment: Have you tried casting them to `int`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: I don't understand why I need to cast if it's already int in the DB.

Comment: Maybe because Laravel doesn't take the DB column type into consideration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model, you should define the field as an integer in the `$cast` attribute.

```php
protected $casts = [
    'field_name' => 'integer',
];
```

You can read the docs for more information by opening the following documentation [link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting).

Answer (score 3):

mysqlnd extension doesn't solve the issue on it's own.
With it also install nd_pdo_mysql extension then it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Installing and enabling mysqlnd extension can solve this problem.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Ii doesn't. This problem happens on Homestead (tried on Homestead 10.1.1) which by default comes with mysqlnd enabled. The problem is still there.